# R sorting keeping track

Tags: r, sorting, match

Hi I am trying to keep track of an initial order of some of my elements in a sorted table. Here is a little toy example :

```
initialTable=data.frame(
  key=runif(30, min=0, max=10000),
  category=as.integer(runif(30, min=0, max=3))
)
```

Then we have the order of the lines according to **key** in the sorted table:

```
lineOrder=order(initialTable$key)
```

And the ordered final table:

```
finalTable=initialTable[lineOrder,]
```

We have interest in those elements and want to keep track of their indexes in the new table:

```
listOfIndexOfInterest=which(initialTable$category==1)
```

So now is how I badly mmanage it :

```
listOfNewPosition=c()
for(i in listOfIndexOfInterest){
  listOfNewPosition=c(listOfNewPosition,which(lineOrder==i))
}
```

Finally the goal is to have the same output for those two commands :

```
initialTable[listOfIndexOfInterest,]
finalTable[listOfNewPosition,]
```

Of course I could tell you more about the reason, but to make it simple, a lot of huge tables are ordered in the same way and I want to build only one time some list of element of interest in a given order !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicely enough, `order(lineOrder)` can be used to invert the action of `lineOrder`:

```
identical(initialTable, finalTable[order(lineOrder),])
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store the initial order as a new column. Then you can `match` on the original index as desired.

```
set.seed(1)
initialTable=data.frame(
  key=runif(30, min=0, max=10000),
  category=as.integer(runif(30, min=0, max=3))
)

initialTable$initialOrder <- seq_len(nrow(initialTable))
finalTable <- initialTable[order(initialTable$key),]
listOfIndexOfInterest=which(initialTable$category==1)

finalTable[match(listOfIndexOfInterest,finalTable$initialOrder),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but asking is sometimes healthy, here is my answer :

```
listOfNewPosition=order(lineOrder)[listOfIndexOfInterest]
```

Reorder the ordered position do the job ...